# Which three points to use to calculate a frustum plane?

Tags: mathematics, optimization, frustum, frustum-culling

So I have a view frustum I'm going to be using for frustum culling. I have a method that finds the cross-product of three points but since each side of the frustum has four corners I don't know which three to use and in which order.

Point numbers:

### [image: Picture of the points]

My question is, does anyone know what order and which points to use?

Comment: What is the "cross product of three points?" A cross-product is an operation between two vectors (and interpreting points in space as vectors is probably not going to give you the desired results for this particular application). Do you mean you're taking three points (say, 2, 0, and 4) making vectors from them (say 2->0, 0->4) and then taking the cross product of those two vectors?

Comment: @JoshPetrie Cross product is just the name I found online, to see the method I have written checkout: https://github.com/Zormion/DiodeEngine3D/blob/master/src/toolbox/Maths.java, the method is called crossProduct, near the bottom.

Comment: That is... a very unique bit of code. :(

Comment: It will be cleaned up once I'm finished with it, I just wanted to make it as legible as possible for the debugging process.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't really help explain what you're doing; that's not a cross product. That's something else. I think you're going to have to describe your intended algorithm in more detail. It's very unclear what you're trying to do. The *likely* answer is that it doesn't *matter* which three points you pick, as long as you are consistent in doing so and perform the math in a fashion that is consistent with the rest of your math (in terms of, for example, following the right-hand rule). What is your goal, and how are you attempting to reach it?

Comment: So what it's doing is taking point 1, subtracting point 2 and then finding the cross product of that and point 2, or at least it should.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37132/discussion-between-josh-petrie-and-zormion).

Answer (score 1):

It's not that you can't point the normals randomly inward/outward, as long as you test them appropriately. It's easier to point them either all-in, or all-out so that the dot products of a contained point are either **all** positive or **all** negative. This makes an generic, iterative `if` test possible.

The cross-product of two *vectors* is a third vector, perpendicular to both; it is also the normal of the plane that contains both inputs.

For the front face, you can do:

```
 cross(normalize(5-7), normalize(6-7))
```

The in- or out-wardness of the direction produced doesn't matter. You can simply breakpoint this, once, see if the calculated normal is positive or negative, and then adjust the `if (dot)` within the iterative plane test accordingly. I viewed the front face from the "outside" along its normal and chose counter-clockwise points, starting at the "top-left" corner. Pick a point on the face, call it "top-left", then wind counter-clockwise around the face's normal. Your hand-drawn diagram has everything you need.